# order of products of elements in a group

Tags: group-theory

we know that if $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle=\{e\}$ and $ab=ba$ then $O(ab)=\operatorname{lcm}\big(O(a),O(b)\big)$ but what can we say about converse of it. Is $O(ab)=\operatorname{lcm}\big(O(a),O(b)\big)$ always implying  that $\langle a\rangle\cap\langle b\rangle=\{e\}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we can take $a=b$ as generators of a cyclic group $C_n$ for $n>1$ odd so that $a^2$ also has order $n$. Then $O(ab)=n=lcm(O(a),O(b))$, but $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle=\langle a\rangle =C_n\neq e$.

Comment: thank you.is there any example that $a\neq b$

Comment: Yes, take $a=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \cr 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ and $b=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \cr 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$ in $GL_2(\Bbb Q)$. Then $O(ab)=\infty=lcm((O(a),O(b))$, but $\langle a\rangle \cap \langle b\rangle\neq e$.